# WIX Web Project installer removes manually added virtual directory

Tags: iis, web-applications, wix

We have a project web installer that installs, upgrades etc. properly.  The only issue is that on upgrade we have a problem with a virtual directory created inside the application manually via the IIS manager.  We have some statically linked files which can be installed in different ways, if using a cluster it makes more sense to throw them on a network file share/DFS rather than copy them individually (they are very large).

Is there a way that I can have the Wix Web project installer not remove manually created virtual directories inside our application on an upgrade?  Or at least detect them and preserve them?

We are using a standard wix iis installation:

```
<!-- IIS website. Inside a Component, <WebSite> creates a new Web Site. Outside a Component, it's a look up. -->
<iis:WebSite Id='WS.WebSite'
    Description='[WEBSITE]'
    Directory='DI.InstallDirectory'>
</iis:WebSite>

<Component Id="CO.VirtualDirectory"
             Guid="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
             KeyPath="yes">
    <!-- The WebSite attribute ties to a <WebSite> element in the setup file -->
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VD.VirtualDirectory"
                       Alias="[VIRTUALDIRECTORY]"
                       Directory="DI.InstallDirectory"
                       WebSite="WS.WebSite" >
      <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WP.WebDirProperties" DefaultDocuments="overview.aspx" />
      <!-- Turn the Virtual Directory into a web application. -->
      <iis:WebApplication Id="WA.WebApplication"
                          Name="xxx"
                          WebAppPool="AP.ApplicationPool" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
    <!-- This is pretty important. If the CreateFolder isn't there the WebVirtualDir won't get created as there are no files in this component.
         http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03483.html -->
    <CreateFolder />
  </Component>
```

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling with verbose logging enabled to see what's causing it to remove the virtual directories. I'm guessing it's some freaky voodoo magic coming from a combination of Windows Installer, WiX's custom actions and IIS.